Flutter integration test -d web-server specify custom chrome path for testing
I have chrome for test version 123.
Chrome that I normally use for browsing is version 125.
My chromedriver is version 123 which is not compatible with chrome 125.
I run flutter tests using -
flutter drive --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart --target=integration_test/001_test.dart -d web-server --web-browser-flag="--disable-web-security"

I dont want to upgrade my chrome driver. I want to keep it the a fixed version.
How can I run flutter tests on my chrome for testing which is at path ~/Application/chrome-linux64/chrome
I get following error :
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "SessionNotCreatedException (500): session not
created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 123
Current browser version is 125.0.6422.60 with binary path /opt/google/chrome/chrome".

I want flutter integration tests to use path ~/Application/chrome-linux64/chrome instead of /opt/google/chrome/chrome
~/Application/chrome-linux64/chrome --version --> 123
/opt/google/chrome/chrome --version --> 125

I set CHROME_EXECUTABLE env variable but flutter doesnt use it.
echo $CHROME_EXECUTABLE 
/home/aseem/Applications/chrome-linux64/chrome

